# Get the value that a user selected from an ngFor list

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

Here's the code that I tried making it to work but I'm probably just doing something wrong.

HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngFor='let parts of parts$'>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" (click)="onCategorySelect($event)" value= "parts.Category">{{parts.Category}}</a>
    </ng-container>
```

.TS:

```
  parts$: Parts[];
  selectedCategory: Parts[];
  constructor(private ApiService:ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    return this.ApiService.getParts().subscribe(data => {this.parts$ = data});
  }

  onCategorySelect($x: any){
    this.selectedCategory = this.parts$.filter(element => element.Category === $x.target.value);
  }
```

I want to get the specific category that the user has selected.

Comment: Why is it an `<anchor>` tag? What is it supposed to be? A button?

Comment: It's just a simple list of available categories that a user can click.

Comment: You can simply pass the current value of `for` in the click event handler like this `(click)="onCategorySelect(parts.Category)"`

Comment: You can simplify that even further by doing the variable assignment in your HTML as well. `<a (click)="selectedCategory=parts.Category"></a>`

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass in the given value into the `click` function like so

```
<ng-container *ngFor='let parts of parts$'>
  <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" (click)="onCategorySelect(parts.Category)" value= "parts.Category">{{parts.Category}}</a>
</ng-container>
```

// Inside component

```
onCategorySelect(category: any){
  this.selectedCategory = category;
}
```